# Any idiom for "having experienced something long before someone else"?

Tags: idiom-request

For example, when someone is trying hard to win a competition, but someone else has won a similar one years ago, there's this expression in Persian that says "What someone is trying to do now is a memory to others", meaning that someone is boastfully more experienced than someone else in something.
Is there any similar idiom or expression in English?

Comment: [**Deja vu**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/deja_vu): 'A feeling of having already experienced the present situation', perhaps?

Comment: @Void - But it has nothing to do with boasting about "being more experienced than someone else".

Comment: Not sure quite what you're getting at, but you could be looking for a boast like, "I was winning competitions when you were still in diapers."

Comment: Perhaps **"Been there, done that"**, which can be used as a slang shortening of "*That is old news, because I have* been there and *I have* done that",